# Creating an event that triggers the pipeline when a ACR is updated with new image

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry, acr

when ACR is updated with latest images automatically pipeline need to trigger in ADO, How can I prevent this, or is there a better way of acheiving what I want?
Need event triggers for ADO pipeline

Comment: having some doubts regarding

Comment: - container: string # identifier for the container resource,actually what we have to present here, before that we need to create acr service connection ?

Comment: please provide sample values in below code: example

Comment: You could check the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-containers.

Comment: pipeline is not triggering when i update the acr with latest images

Comment: Have you set `trigger`? Triggers are not enabled by default and need to be set explicitly.

Comment: trigger:
- none

 

resources:
containers:
- container: 'myid'
type: ACR
azureSubscription: 'sc'
resourceGroup: 'rg-eu2-t-spoke-s-app'
registry: 'acreu2aks'
repository: 'webfrontend' # sample app repos
trigger: true

pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

Comment: above comment with exact code using in pipeline

Comment: `trigger: true` is not correct, please check the example in the following reply to set the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to consume a container image as part of your CI/CD pipeline, you can achieve it using `Resources: containers`. A container resource can be a public or private Docker Registry, or Azure Container Registry.

```
resources:          # types: pipelines | repositories | containers | builds | packages
  containers:
  - container: string # identifier for the container resource      
    type: string # type of the registry like ACR, GCR etc. 
    azureSubscription: string # Azure subscription (ARM service connection) for container registry;
    resourceGroup: string # resource group for your ACR
    registry: string # registry for container images
    repository: string # name of the container image repository in ACR
    trigger: # Triggers are not enabled by default and need to be set explicitly
      tags:
        include: [ string ]  # image tags to consider the trigger events, optional; defaults to any new tag
        exclude: [ string ]  # image tags on discard the trigger events, optional; defaults to none
```

For example:

```
resources:         
  containers:
  - container: petStore      
    type: ACR  
    azureSubscription: ContosoARMConnection
    resourceGroup: ContosoGroup
    registry: petStoreRegistry
    repository: myPets
    trigger: 
      tags:
        include: 
        - production*
```

or

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: mycontainer # name of the container (Alias) 
    type: ACR # type of registry
    azureSubscription: arm-connection # name of the ARM service connection
    resourceGroup: rg-storage-eastus # Azure resource group with the container
    registry: mycontainerregistry # Azure container registry name
    repository: hello-world # name of the of container image collection
    trigger:
      tags:
      - latest # tag for the container image to use
```

Comment: i used above code with tags latest , still am facing same its not triggering

Comment: Could you try a specific tag?

Comment: Did you set the trigger as `trigger: 
      tags:
        include: 
        - production* `?